# Create list of vectors using rep()

Tags: r, list, vector, lapply, rep

I want to create a list which is eight times the vector `c(2,6)`, i.e. a list of 8 vectors.

- WRONG: `object = as.list(rep(c(2,6),8))` results instead in a list of 16 single numbers: `2 6 2 6 2 6 2 6 ...`
- I tried `drop=0` but that didn't help, and I can't get `lapply` to work.

(My context: 
I have a function in which a subfunction will call a numbered list object. 
The number will be in a loop and therefore change, and the number and loop size is dependent on user values so I don't know what it'll be. If the user doesn't enter a list of vector values for one of the variables, I need to set a default.

The subfunction is expecting e.g. `c(2,6)`
The subfunction is currently looping 8 times so I need a list which is eight times `c(2,6)`.

Comment: Are you looking for `rep(list(c(2,6)),8)`?

Comment: awesome, thanks, I KNEW it would be something silly. You wanna make this an answer so I can give you the rep?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`rep(list(c(2,6)),8)` is the answer - thanks to Nicola in comments.